# App cannot connect to Google servers for access to Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been working on an android app for the past little while and I wanted to set it up to connect to Google Maps. I've been writing it inside Eclipse with the ADT plugins. I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api) but I've been getting the following Error when I try to load maps.

"failed to load map. error contacting google servers. this is probably an authentication issue (but could be do to network errors)"

Since I can access google maps in other apps it has to be an authentication error. I've tried uninstalling the app from my phone but that does not fix the error.

The SHA1 that eclipse is using (according to window > properties > android > build) is 58:EF:6F:DE:DE:B4:4E:EB:20:15:68:39:08:5D:87:32:FE:20:99:99

I used this to generate an API key in the google console which you can see contained below in my manifest file. The app I specified in the console was 58:EF:6F:DE:DE:B4:4E:EB:20:15:68:39:08:5D:87:32:FE:20:99:99;com.example.test. It may be worth noting that I'm loading the map inside an activity located in the gui package, not the com.example.test package that contains MainActivity.

I've been testing this on my nexus 5 by clicking play in eclipse while the phone is plugged into my computer.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBsTBliiyhE2G4Navzfc1ANeI9f7JwAtEM" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="gui.SetLocationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_set_location" >
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: There isn't an error per se. It's just what comes up in the LogCat

Comment: Right, but it still might gives us some information. Post it please.

Comment: No I meant there is no stacktrace. That message is all the shows up.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct SHA1 key. Follow the steps in the [Google guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key).

Comment: Well the key I posted is the key that eclipse uses. I ran keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore in the .android directory that ellipse uses to sign the app with a debug certificate when you hit play to confirm it's the same as getting the certificate the way I listed in my post. They came out as the same. That guide is the one I posted in my initial post.