# new googlemap v2 API key issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I created an application with a map, but the map does not load tiles.

In the console I get the log:

```
ru.gs.maptest I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

ru.gs.maptest E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

For create project I used a template in AndroidStudio (new project->...->GoogleMapActivity->...)

AndroidStudio generates manifest file according to the rules described in the documentation. only need to insert the map key.

1. obtain a debug key fingerprint
2. get packege name
3. in api console get map api key
4. put key to manifest
5. run and we get a gray map.

everything looks right, everything is done through the documentation, but does not work. I didn't create the program for the first time, I have work projects with map. I began to understand the problem.

I checked everything, I changed packages, I created a new key, I created keys for the release, I added the manifest different tags, used all tips are found шт stackoverflow, doing it all over again, using different networks, different devices, cleanr and delete program on device, resets the device and computer. it remains only to reinstall the OS.

The old my program is similar to the new program as two drops of water. But the old program works and the new is not working.

I decided to assign a new project packagename of the old project for which I have the old key.(use gradle flavors) And map start downloading tiles.

After some more experiments I conclude that:

### the new created map api keys does not work

try to create a simple project. you also have the same problem?

***this Google service error?***

---

p.s. I can put the source code if needed

people who have problems like me(these days):

[For google maps api v2, what is the limit for creating new android maps key(s) and adding applications to single key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954245/for-google-maps-api-v2-what-is-the-limit-for-creating-new-andriod-maps-keys-a/23961622#23961622)

[App cannot connect to Google servers for access to Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23985402/1438218)

[Google Maps fragment showing blank grey map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950734/google-maps-fragment-showing-blank-grey-map)

[Google Maps Android API Authorization failure - has this service changed in the last few months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466789/google-maps-android-api-authorization-failure-has-this-service-changed-in-the)

[Google maps suddenly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805769/google-maps-suddenly-not-working)

Comment: Uninstall the old apk and re-install it one again. If you this problem repeated. Share your Log cat errors.

Comment: I did it. Uninstall app from device, Clear project, invalidate cache and re-install again. I posted the logcat in body. or something more needed?

Comment: May be some problems in registration. www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ follow this one. It helps you